# 'TextRenderer.MeasureText' giving distinct size than 'Graphics.MeasureString'

Tags: .net, vb.net, string, winforms, text

I suppose that exist a known clarification about why those methods always return distinct sizes, but anyways I will explain the problem a little:

I've subclassed a Progressbar, when I try to get the size of the same text with the same font, I get distinct values, `TextRenderer.MeasureText`gives me a rounded value of **13** height and **300** width while `Graphics.MeasureString` gives me a very precise height of **13,xxxxxx** and a minor width of **275,xxxxxxx**

Why happens that?.

I'm not doing nothing especial in the code, just I've tried to use both methods to compare whether it gives me the same result or not to decide which to use in my code.

The overload of `TextRenderer.MeasureText` that I've tried to use is:

```
TextRenderer.MeasureText(String, Font)
```

And the `Graphics.MeasureString` method expects the same parameters:

```
Graphics.MeasureString(String, Font)
```

Comment: Because `TextRender` returns a `Size`, `MeasureString` returns `SizeF`.  Depending on where you are putting the Text, one may be more appropriate than the other... the FONT arg is usually more like `thisCtl.Font` so that it is accurate.

Comment: Oh, was strange 'cause both returned me a Single, but yes I suppse that the Size/SizeFloat explains everything... just I wanted to avoid instancing a Graphics object just to measure the text inside the control, do you know another method that gives a SizeF structure without need of creating a graphics object?. PS: like always I say feel free to post that as an answer to mark it

Comment: A control shouldnt need to use MeasureString, but 275 vs 300 seems wrong, which is why I mentioned the Font thing.  You also might want to include the padding stuff for the control.

Comment: Ok, thanks, it's solved. PS: I've used the same font to test them, the font used by the control

Comment: You might want to look at `ProgressBarRenderer` if you are drawing to one there might be internal margins defined which will alter your results. nevermind - there are none for it.  The `CheckBoxRender` gives you the size of the check and margin between it and the start of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextRenderer.MeasureText` returns a `Size` so the values are integer.  `Graphics.MeasureString` returns a `SizeF` containing floats.

Both are "raw values" though.  When testing to see if some text will fit somewhere, you may also need to take into account `Control.Padding` which each Type may implement differently.

275 vs 300 seems like a large variance though.  I have a checkbox thing that returns `82, 13` vs `82.85806, 13.8251925).